# how to UnSelect all rows in GridView - asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to UnSelect all rows in GridView - asp.net ?

if i select one row in GridView and make any refresh, how to unselect this row ?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you can set the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex.aspx) to `-1`.

```
gridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Note: You will need to do this after each databind of new data to the GridView.

Comment: In your answer you cite `SelectedIndex`, but then in your code sample you use `SelectedRow`. I think you mean to use `SelectedIndex` throughout.

Answer (score 0):

As SvDevMan81 noted, you'd set the GridView's `SelectedIndex` property to -1.

Similarly, if you have an editable grid and you want to revert the grid to its read-only mode you can set the GridView's `EditIndex` property to -1.